# Do not close Photoswipe if users swipes down/up

Tags: android, ios, mobile, photoswipe

My Photoswipe gallery automatically closes/hides, if the user swipes up or down.

I cannot find a way to disable this feature. does someone know how to solve this?

best regards,

Richie

Answer (score 1):

Just set `closeOnVerticalDrag` option to `false`.

[Photoswipe Documentation - Options](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/options.html)

Comment: this is the solution!